# Lazy __FILE__ and __LINE__ Population

Tags: c++, file, macros, line, lazy-evaluation

So I have a function which I want to evaluate a result, and if the result is a failure the function will log the file and line number:

```
void foo(const bool is_failure, const char* file = __FILE__, const int line = __LINE__) {
    if(is_failure) cout << "Failure returned at " << file << '#' << line << endl;
}
```

I can call this like `foo(func())` and if `func` returns `true` then `foo` will log out failure. The problem is that the `file` and `line` parameters are returning the file and line that `foo` is declared at. Is there a way that I can accomplish this other than using a macro?

Comment: There are use cases for macros, and this is one of them.

Comment: Maybe one day we'll get [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location) but it's not part of the language yet.

Comment: @NathanOliver I honestly wish that I could write this all as a macro, but in my actual function I do: `bool foo(const bool is_failure, const char* file = __FILE__, const int line = __LINE__) { (is_failure) { cout << "Failure returned at " << file << '#' << line << endl; } return is_failure;
}` and I can't figure out how to force evaluation of `func()` *before* it is passed to the macro.

Comment: @JonathanMee Make a macro that calls `foo` like `#define foo_caller(bool_var) foo((bool_var), __FILE__, __LINE__);`.  Then you use `foo_caller` instead of `foo` in your source code.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah that's what I'm doing right now... I was hoping for something better.

Comment: Someone might but I can't think of anything easier or simpler than doing the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can accomplish this ...

Yes.

You can write a function-like macro that expands into a function call, and passes `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` as arguments. Since the macro is expanded at call site, that's the line which populates those macros:

```
#define FOO(arg) foo((arg), __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

> ... other than using a macro?

I don't think so. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are pre processor macros. Pre processing always happens before compilation.

Equivalent functionality is not implementable in standard C++ without (those) macros. A non-macro feature `std::source_location` has been proposed in [n4519](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4519.pdf) as a Technical Specification. When passed as a default argument, it will be populated by the call site. Example from the proposal:

> ```
> struct s {
>     source_location member = source_location::current();
>     int other_member;
>
>     s(source_location loc = source_location::current())
>         : member(loc)   // values of member will be from call-site
>     {}
>
>     s(int blather)      // values of member should be hereabouts
>         : other_member(blather)
>     {}
>
>     s(double)           // values of member should be hereabouts
>     {}
> };
> ```

Adapted for your function:

```
void foo(const bool is_failure, source_location loc = source_location::current());
```

Until (and unless) this feature is incorporated into the standard, you can rely on either a macro, or implementation specific features such as `__builtin_LINE` and`__builtin_FILE` in GCC that make it possible to implement `std::source_location` or equivalent.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you use `__LINE__` or `std::source_location`. You cannot get the location of the *caller* with either.

Comment: @n.m. I added an explanation of how `__LINE__` can be used to get the location of the caller (of the macro), and how `std::source_location` can be used without a macro.

Comment: "When passed as a default argument, it will be populated by the call site" that's an interesting decision.

Comment: @n.m. I think you're agreeing with this answer's suggested `source_location` default argument, right? This is the example: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e74eb647d5952d76 from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location which I believe demonstrates this answer, right?

Comment: ©JonathanMee yes this should work